# Why is iOS11 beta search bar disappearing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios11

iOS11 beta seems to have broken my search bar.

This video - https://youtu.be/6F1mO3l61sU - shows what happens in iOS11 (on the left) and iOS 9.3 (on the right).

This seems to be partially to do with the fact that the tableview on the right is in a view controller that takes up the right half of the screen.

The search controller and tableview are built in code. 
I've tried `[self.mysearchcontroller.searchbar sizeToFit]` and that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. It's even worse when using the app on iOS11 when built from XCode 8 - the whole view collapses rather than just disappearing.

Comment: I noticed that in the new beta the bar doesn't collapse, but it moves to the top of the screen and the width seems to be taken from the whole screen - not the view controller. So now I see the search but the cancel button is not visible since it's off the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: I would suggest there's another reason for it taking the screen's width instead of the view controller's. We have an inset view controller successfully showing and using the search bar in iOS11 correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There was an issue with iOS 8 previously where we were setting this property to fix a layout issue only.

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

should be

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
```

If you have this too, either set this to 'false' or delete the line of code. We no longer support iOS 8 so just deleting this line of code fixed my problem. I suppose if you have this for the same reason you may want to dynamically set it to still support iOS 8 but also support iOS 11.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I already had `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false` . Removing the line made no difference.